# Solidity basics: what "msg.sender" stands for

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I just started to learn Solidity as a personal challenge. I'm not a developer so I've a loooooong way to go.

I'm following the Ethereum.org tutorial, here is what I've got doubt about: What does `[msg.sender]` stand for? I guess it is the wallet address of who triggered the contract, but I'm not sure.

Comment: RTFM

"msg.sender (address): sender of the message (current call)"

Answer (score 42):

> `msg.sender` (`address`): sender of the message (current call)

`msg.sender` will be the person who's currently connecting with the contract.

Later on, you'll probably deal with contracts connecting with contracts. In that case, the contract that is creating the call would be the `msg.sender`.

Check out the documentation here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties

Comment: I am a beginner myself, so just to be clear: Can `msg.sender` in a contract be generally described as the address from the "entity" that currently interacts with this contract?

Answer (score 4):

Let's make it very simple.

```
There are two types of accounts in the Ethereum Chain
1). Externally Owned Accounts(EOA) [Person]
2). Contracts Accounts [Contracts on Chain]
```

Both accounts have their addresses.

- **Now, look at an example.**

Wallet address of personA [(EOA)](https://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/account-types-gas-and-transactions.html) is
`0x0cE446987406E92DF41614C46F1d6df9Cc925847`.

Contract Address of `Math.sol` is
`0x0cE446987406E92DF41614C46F1d6df9Cc753869` and
`Math.sol` contains `ContractA`

Contract Address of `Addition.sol` is
`0x0cE446987406E92DF41614C46F1d6df9Cc357241` and
`Addition.sol` contains `ContractB`

Here, one of the functions of `ContractB` is called from `ContractA`.

So, whenever `personA` calls any functions of `ContractA`.

```
In this scenario, if you print or get `msg.sender` and `tx.origin` inside function of `ContractB` then the result would be like this

msg.sender = `0x0cE446987406E92DF41614C46F1d6df9Cc753869` // You will get address of `ContractA`
tx.origin  = `0x0cE446987406E92DF41614C46F1d6df9Cc925847` // personA's (EOA) Wallet Address
```

Comment: Where is functionC()? Where is Math.sol? Please give more background to this solution. This may clarify msg.sender and txt.origin, which is an important concept for beginners.

Comment: The answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

`msg.sender (address)`: means sender of the message (current call)

on the other hand

`address owner = msg.sender;`

The `msg.sender` is the address that has called or initiated a function or created a transaction. Now, this address could be of a contract or even a person like you and me.

That's why you may use `msg.sender` instead of `msg.sender()`