# Is it possible to run my Solidity Smart Contract function on my frontend from a specific account

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm currently working on creating a web3 browser game and I ran into an issue. I have a method in my SmartContract for giving players tokens and its **onlyOwner**. I want to be able to run it in **my code** but not let other people run it. Since Users could easily just give themselves free coins if they did that. Im Using [Web3Js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/getting-started.html) and i'm not the most familiar with it yet. ***Is there a way that i can run my function from MY address in my frontend, instead of it running from the connected users?*** All Feedback is welcome, thanks for your time.

Status: Not Anwsered

Answer (score 0):

Your user controls the frontend, so if you allow it to call a function you are also allowing the user to do so.

Comment: More of a Web3Js question... I'm looking for a way to let my frontend execute this code even when i'm not connected (When a different user is).

Answer (score 0):

> there a way that i can run my function from MY address in my frontend, instead of it running from the connected users?

You check in the smart contract Solidity code that the transaction comes from your address using [msg.sender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572142/315168).

Comment: Yes i know that, i want the frontend to run the function even when im not connected (when a different person is)

Comment: Then you need to add smart contract logic for this how do you authorise this another person.